# WPF Load Images Based on Value

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate, staticresource

I have a `List<object>` which contains a list of of values for each object which I want to access and create a set image based on the values - don't really want to use a Converter.

I have the below which works:

```
<Image x:Name="Desk1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Width="50" Height="50">
   <Image.Style>
      <Style TargetType="Image">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Office[0].Desks[0].Status} Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack:///application:,,,/Resources/DeskAvailable.png"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Office[0].Desks[0].Status} Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack:///application:,,,/Resources/DeskUnavailable.png"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Office[0].Desks[0].Status} Value="2">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack:///application:,,,/Resources/DeskUnknown.png"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

But I don't want to have to write all this for many desks.

So I've created a Resource:

```
<Windows.Resources>
<DataTemplate x:Key = "DeskImage">
<Image>
   <Image.Style>
      <Style TargetType="Image">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack:///application:,,,/Resources/DeskAvailable.png"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack:///application:,,,/Resources/DeskUnavailable.png"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Value="2">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack:///application:,,,/Resources/DeskUnknown.png"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </Image.Style>
</Image>
</Windows.Resources>
```

Which I was hoping to access for each image and just pass it the value in Office[x].Desk[x].Status to determine which image to load. But this is the bit I'm unsure on how to create an image type in xaml and pass the value to the static resource.

Something like:

```
<Image x:Name="Desk1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Width="50" Height="50">
   [pseudocode]
      Bind to Office[x].Desks[x].Status
      Pass data to Resource and load correct image
   [/pseudo]
</image>
```

Comment: Is it really `Office[x].Desk[x]` or `Office[x].Desk[y]` for all combinations of x and y? What is the layout the Images? An x by y Grid?

Comment: @Clemens Yes the layout is just a grid. And I'm not sure what you're asking 'is it really Office[x].Desk[x]' sorry. It's a List<Office> and Office contains a List<Desk> and desk has a member called Status so each image will be based off of a Status of a particular desk in a particular offce

Comment: x and x would only get `Office[0].Desk[0]`, `Office[1].Desk[1]` etc. i.e. only the diagonal elements in the Grid.

Comment: ah yes sorry - it can be any combination. i.e. in the grid I'm hoping to load for example ```Office[3].Desk[7].Status``` and then use that to load the correct image from the DataTemplate

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using nested ItemsControls.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Office}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Desks}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Width="50" Height="50">
                            <Image.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Image">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="0">
                                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack:///application:,,,/Resources/DeskAvailable.png"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="1">
                                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack:///application:,,,/Resources/DeskUnavailable.png"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="2">
                                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="pack:///application:,,,/Resources/DeskUnknown.png"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Image.Style>
                        </Image>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```